# Copy list of arrays to list of slices works wrong

Tags: arrays, go, slice

There is an array type:

```
const Size = 16
type idType [Size]byte
```

and to structure types:

```
type srcListItem struct {
    id idType
}
type destListItem struct {
    id []byte
}
```

I initialize source list with two items like this:

```
srcList := make([]srcListItem, 2)
for i := 0; i < Size; i++ {
    srcList[0].id[i] = byte(i)
    srcList[1].id[i] = byte(i + Size)
}
```

Then I try to copy it to two slices of `destListItem` type. When copying one of them I use item, and to copy another index is used:

```
for i, item := range srcList {
    fmt.Println("id slice: ", srcList[i].id)
    item1 := destListItem {
        id: item.id[:],
    }
    destList1 = append(destList1, item1)

    item2 := destListItem {
        id: srcList[i].id[:],
    }
    destList2 = append(destList2, item2)
}
```

the output of print result slices is:

```
destList1 items array:  [{[16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31]} {[16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31]}]
destList2 items array:  [{[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15]} {[16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31]}]
```

Tell me please why items in destList1 contains identical ids?
Here is complete source code: https://play.golang.org/p/IJM5cllSb1B

Thanks.

P. S. I know some workarounds. For example the result will be correct in both cases if the source list will be of `[]*srcListItem` type. 
But why it work so strange as is?

Comment: Can you come up with a _simple_ example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is a result of `item` going out of scope and the for loop reusing the memory. This means that when you append `item` to your slice, you hold on to it even after it "goes out of scope". When the for loop changes the memory's underlying value, you see those changes reflected in your slice.

Comment: Suppose that it works correctly when using index `srcList[i].id[:]` because of golang creates one more copy of `srcListItem`. Is it expected behavior or it'a a bug in golang optimizer?

Comment: I don't think its a bug. I think you can't count on the value of the iterator pass that iteration.

Comment: @Leo It's not a bug. `srcList[i]` and `item` don't share the same place in memory. You could think of it this way: on each iteration `range` copies the value in `srcList[i]` to `item` resuing the memory it allocated for `item` at the loop's start. And doing `item[:]` returns a slice that references `item`'s storage, ie its memory, ie the memory the range loop allocated for item and is reusing on each iteration.